# Auto shoot script for VR? (changing Script)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am integrating my game to VR and now i wanted to change my controlling. In the script given bellow when the player press the mouse button the gun fires the bullet but now in VR i don't want my game to be controlled by any controller. what i want is when player moves his head and the focus point comes to the Enemy it starts shooting without pressing any button(I mean auto shoot). what should i do??

```
grausing System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;
    public float fireRate = 15f;
    public float impactForce = 30f;

    public Camera fpsCam;

    public GameObject impactEffect;

    private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
        {
            nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

            Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
            if (target != null)
            {
                target.TakeDamage(damage); 
            }

            if(hit.rigidbody != null)
            {
                hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * impactForce);
            }
            GameObject ImpactEffectGO = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
            Destroy(ImpactEffectGO, 2f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you  already have an existing shooting mechanic, simply changing up the `Update()` should do what you want

```
void Update () {

    if (Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
    {
        nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
        Shoot();
    }
}
```

Comment: That would fire continuously, not specifically when focusing on an enemy.

Comment: @Chad well, he's doing the raycasting checks in `Shoot()`